# AFNetworking POST Request failed Code=-1011 (400)

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, http-status-code-400

I have a webservice and I can successfully make post calls to it via Postman utility. On Postman the settings are
[image]

I using AFNetworking. This my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"offset": @"1", @"csrf-token": @"63b164ea557b4aba694f81520c71972fa43a9772"};
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:@"http://simple.com/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7a6c5240 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a6b5360> { URL: http://simple.com/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 31 May 2015 15:40:26 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    "Set-Cookie" = "csrf-token=5589461e87b28a538953ccac4168bf1f98b20b1ds%3A40%3A%22f52bda5262260a3ee0a10efcf48a6a49c11e4103%22%3B; path=/, PHPSESSID=803db60816b9f8203fb8feca01c130b6; path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.17";
```

This is without AFNetworking:

```
NSString *post = @"offset=1&csrf-token=63b164ea557b4aba694f81520c71972fa43a9772";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://simple.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
```

and again an error: 400

Please help solve the problem

Comment: @ilesh Corrections for my problem I described in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved his problem.

The fact that the server keeps the session with specific **CSRF token**. My mistake was that I used the same token, in a browser, and mobile device. Therefore, the server and did not give details as getting the wrong POST request.

**My solution:** I first get a server **CSRF token**, and then for a further `POST` queries I use the resulting token. In response to the POST request I get a status 200 and the data I needed.

True `AFNetworking` I do not really help in this problem, so I had to use the standard`NSURLConnection` (I put the code in question). Maybe in the future someone does come in handy!

Thanks to all! Good luck to all!